# How to perform swipe down programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to refresh a application by swiping down programmatically (for example Facebook app) from a service running in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Implement swiperefersh layout in your screen. Fetch server data from service save somewhere then notify the screen using broadcast receiver after setrefresh  swiperefersh true fetch local cache content then make it false

Answer (score 0):

Not generally.  Apps can't send touch events to one another.  It can be done if its your app in the foreground receiving the gesture (although then there's easier ways to do this than faking a gesture), or it can maybe be done if you're an accessibility service (but they won't allow you on Google Play if you're using accessibility for something like this).

If its a personal app, you can checkout AccessibilityService and dispatchGesture() for a possible solution.